# In google analytics, hourly data shows user's timezone or the website owner's timezone?

Tags: google, google-analytics

Suppose my google account settings has my timezone as PST. And I have included google analytics on my website. A user opens the site from New york city at 4pm ET. In the hourly dashboard what is shown, PST or ET ?

Answer (score 2):

"The country or territory and the time zone you want to use as the day boundary for your reports, regardless of where the data originates. For example, if you choose United States, Pacific Time, then the beginning and end of each day is calculated based on Pacific Time, even if the hit comes from New York, London, or Moscow."

Source: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1010249?hl=en